# SMTP client using a remote SOCKS5/proxy in Go

Tags: go, email, proxy, smtp

I am trying to create an SMTP client that uses a proxy connection, SOCKS5.

When I use a local host proxy the code successfully creates an SMTP client.

When I try to use a remote proxy, I am getting a `TTL expired`. I am also getting an `EOF` error when trying to use a different proxy connection.

I have set up a proxy server in my localhost, `socks5://dante:maluki@127.0.0.1:1080`

I have also set up an identical proxy server on my remote VM, `socks5://dante:maluki@35.242.186.23:1080`

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/smtp"
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/idna"
    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

const (
    smtpTimeout = time.Second * 60
    smtpPort    = ":25"
)

func init() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
}

func main() {

    // The code works when I use a localhost proxy
    //      socks5://dante:maluki@127.0.0.1:1080

    client, err := newSMTPClient("gmail.com", "socks5://dante:maluki@35.242.186.23:1080")

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    log.Println(client)
}

// establishProxyConnection connects to the address on the named network address
// via proxy protocol
func establishProxyConnection(addr, proxyURI string) (net.Conn, error) {
    // return socks.Dial(proxyURI)("tcp", addr)

    u, err := url.Parse(proxyURI)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)

        return nil, err
    }

    var iface proxy.Dialer

    if u.User != nil {
        auth := proxy.Auth{}

        auth.User = u.User.Username()
        auth.Password, _ = u.User.Password()

        iface, err = proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", u.Host, &auth, &net.Dialer{Timeout: 30 * time.Second})
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)

            return nil, err
        }
    } else {
        iface, err = proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", u.Host, nil, proxy.FromEnvironment())
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)

            return nil, err
        }
    }

    dialfunc := iface.Dial

    return dialfunc("tcp", addr)
}

// newSMTPClient generates a new available SMTP client
func newSMTPClient(domain, proxyURI string) (*smtp.Client, error) {
    domain = domainToASCII(domain)
    mxRecords, err := net.LookupMX(domain)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(mxRecords) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("No MX records found")
    }

    // Attempt to connect to SMTP servers
    for _, r := range mxRecords {

        // Simplified to make the code short

        addr := r.Host + smtpPort

        c, err := dialSMTP(addr, proxyURI)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        return c, err

    }

    return nil, errors.New("failed to created smtp.Client")
}

// dialSMTP is a timeout wrapper for smtp.Dial. It attempts to dial an
// SMTP server (socks5 proxy supported) and fails with a timeout if timeout is reached while
// attempting to establish a new connection
func dialSMTP(addr, proxyURI string) (*smtp.Client, error) {
    // Channel holding the new smtp.Client or error
    ch := make(chan interface{}, 1)

    // Dial the new smtp connection
    go func() {
        var conn net.Conn
        var err error

        conn, err = establishProxyConnection(addr, proxyURI)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        if err != nil {
            ch <- err
            return
        }

        host, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(addr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        client, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
        log.Println(client)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)

            ch <- err
            return
        }
        ch <- client
    }()

    // Retrieve the smtp client from our client channel or timeout
    select {
    case res := <-ch:
        switch r := res.(type) {
        case *smtp.Client:
            return r, nil
        case error:
            return nil, r
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("Unexpected response dialing SMTP server")
        }
    case <-time.After(smtpTimeout):
        return nil, errors.New("Timeout connecting to mail-exchanger")
    }
}

// domainToASCII converts any internationalized domain names to ASCII
// reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode
func domainToASCII(domain string) string {
    asciiDomain, err := idna.ToASCII(domain)
    if err != nil {
        return domain
    }
    return asciiDomain

}
```

Comment: Did you check that the proxy works in the first place with other programs? The problem might not be the code but the setup of your proxy.

Comment: I have tested the proxy with curl, and it works.
```sh
curl -v -x socks5://dante:maluki@35.242.186.23:1080 http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: And where exactly you get the error in your code? Also please reduce your code to the absolute minimum needed to reproduce the problem, i.e. the socks connection and then starting the SMTP dialog.

Comment: I am getting the error at 
```go
client, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
```

Comment: Looks like the host where you are running the proxy on blocks access to port 25. I.-e. port 80 (http) works, port 25 (smtp) not. Several companies do this in order to prevent being misused for sending spam and thus getting a bad reputation. One usually need to use the hosters mail server in order to deliver mails.

Comment: I have updated my firewall rules to allow access

Comment: I have allowed all traffic

Comment: I have ssh into the remote vm where I have the proxy installed, when I ran the code it also fails for the localhost proxy. 
I have updated the firewall rules to allow traffic through port 25. But it still fails

Comment: How can use trafifc the "hosters mail server"?

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich, I have found out Google cloud VPC blocks out SMTP port 25, [https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic)